# Can someone explain me why I can't use in model two has_many through?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new at Ruby on Rails. And I do not understand, why there are can be only one has_many through in model?

```
class Physician < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
  has_many :diagnoses
  has_many :patients, through: :diagnoses

end

class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Diagnosis < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
  has_many :diagnoses
  has_many :physicians, through: :diagnoses
end
```

Comment: It's ambiguous to have two `patients` relations defined through different models.

Comment: What @Yakov said; however you could rename the associations to something like `has_many :diagnosed_patients, through: :diagnoses, source: :patient` and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails the assocations macros (`belongs_to`, `has_one`, `has_many` and `has_and_belongs_to_many`) write an [AssocationReflection](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/MacroReflection.html) which contains all the metadata about the assocation which is kept in a [hash as a class attribute](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reflections).

The name of the assocation is the key used to store the reflection. When you declare multiple assocations with the same name you're just overwriting the previous assocation - this can actually be useful for example when inheriting the assocation or when monkeypatching.

In older versions of Rails redefining a `has_many through:` assocation can raise an `HasManyThroughOrderError` due to a flaw in the implementation which [was fixed in 2018 and backported](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/652258e41a882acccdb9a3ce211dbf356e738b28).

What you really should be doing is to define unique names for each assocation.

```
class Physician < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
  has_many :diagnosed_patients, 
    through: :diagnoses,
    source:  :patient
end

class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
  has_many :diagnoses
  has_many :diagnosing_physicians, 
     through: :diagnoses,
     source:  :physicians
end
```