# Over-writing ActiveRecord association macros

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm building an API for an app that allows users to rate and favorite different ski mountains.  At the moment, my associations are set up as follows:

```
class Mountain < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :ratings
    has_many :users, through: :ratings
    has_many :favorites
    has_many :users, through: :favorites
end
```

```
class Favorite < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :mountain
  belongs_to :user
end
```

```
class Rating < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :mountain
  belongs_to :user
end
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :ratings
    has_many :mountains, through: :ratings
    has_many :favorites
    has_many :mountains, through: :favorites
end
```

The problem here is that User has many mountains through both ratings and favorites, but calling User.first.mountains will only give me mountains through ratings, since that's listed first.  I'll need to utilize both in the app - any guidance here? Same deal for mountains - has many users through both ratings and favorites.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: rename one of them. Maybe even both of them. e.g. rated_mountains and favorited_mountains.

Comment: There is an explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/a/70836501/9548002